# Sublime text 3 coffeescript build

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I keep getting this error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'coffee'
[cmd: ['coffee', '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/opensource/ngprayertimes/prayertimes.coffee']]
[dir: /Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/opensource/ngprayertimes]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

My CoffeeCompiler settings:

```
{


    /**
     * REQUIRED
     *
     * Where your `node` executable lives. If this is not specified, then
     * it is expected to be on Sublime's path.
     *
     * On OSX, for example:
     * `/usr/local/bin`
     */
    "node_path": "/usr/local/bin"


    /**
     * REQUIRED ONLY IF USING `executable` COMPILER
     *
     * Where your `coffee` executable lives.
     *
     * On OSX, for example:
     * `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin`
     */
,    "coffee_path": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/coffee-script/bin"


    /**
     * How should the plugin invoke your coffee executable.
     *
     * This can be the name of the executable if its in your path,
     * or it can be the absolute path to it (although in that case,
     * try to use the `coffee_path` setting).
     *
     * You can find where your executable is by running "which coffee"
     * in your terminal.
     *
     * Defaults:
     *   Windows   -> 'coffee.cmd'
     *   Linux/OSX -> 'coffee'
     */
,    "coffee_executable": "coffee"


    /**
     * Compile without a top-level function wrapper.
     *
     * Defaults to `false`.
     */
,   "bare": true


     /**
      * Show the CoffeeCompile right+click menu option for files of
      * these types.
      *
      * If the list is empty, the menu option will always be shown.
      *
      *
      * If you want to figure out the path to syntax file for a certain
      * filetype, do the following:
      *
      * 1. Open a new file.
      * 2. Hit `ctrl/cmd + shift + P` and set the syntax you want.
      * 3. Open the sublime console by pressing `ctrl/cmd + ~`.
      * 4. Execute `view.settings().get('syntax')` and copy paste the
      *    output here.
      *
      */
,    "syntax_patterns": [
          "Packages/CoffeeScript/CoffeeScript.tmLanguage"
     ,    "Packages/Better CoffeeScript/CoffeeScript.tmLanguage"
     ,    "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"

     ]
}
```

No idea why it's not working although I can convert my coffee to javascript. But I cannot build it?

Comment: Which OS? Where do you coffee / node executables reside?

Comment: Mavericks / `which coffee => /usr/local/bin/coffee` is that how to find it?

Comment: That's right. The coffee command appears to be your path which is ok, the coffee_path in the CoffeeCompiler settings points somewhere else though, does it actually try to use this? If you try changing that to "coffee_path": "/usr/local/bin" does it work? I'mnot familiar with OSX and no longer use sublime so not entirely sure what the problem is and why it doesn't just work but might be worth giving that a go.